# Problemas con safari y API google Maps

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una página que usara geolocalizacion y al parecer todo funciona bien pero en Safari versión 11 me genera un error el geolocation 
mi **código** es:

```
function initMap() {
var map;
var mapCenter;
var latit;
var lon;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        latit = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latit, lon);
        console.log(mapCenter)
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            fullscreenControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            },
            rotateControl: true,
            scaleControl: true
        });
        var markerP = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCenter,
            map: map,
            title: 'Ubicacion actual',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        })
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.code)
        switch (error) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert("No se ha permitido acceso a la posición del usuario")
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                 alert("No se ha permitido acceder a la información de la posicón")
                 break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert("El servicio ha tardado demaciado tiempo en responder")
                break;
            default:
                  alert("Error desconocido")
        }

    })
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation

}

}
 }
```

al llegar a la parte de `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` me manda a la función de error indicando "Error desconocido" Pero esto solo pasa en Safari.

En versión de safari 9 si funciona, pero no logro encontrar en la documentación algo que me oriente ya que si funciono en safari unas veces y de la nada ya no funciono.

Answer (score 2):

Trata de utilizar "https" en dado caso que no lo estés utilizando, también recuerda que `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` no te garantiza regresar un resultado, ya que el usuario puede denegar el permiso de localización haciéndote imposible localizarlo.

Como recomendación aparte puedes inicializar el mapa con un centro por defecto no enviado por el usuario.